# TYPO3 fluid: f:format.html in backend removes links

Tags: typo3, backend, flux, fluid

I am using flux 9.5.0 in TYPO3 9.5.31 to create a simle "text" content element.

It has a preview section that is displayed in the TYPO3 backend with [<f:format.html>](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/9.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Format/Html.html):

```
  <f:section name="Preview">
    <f:format.html>{settings.text}</f:format.html>
  </f:section>
```

Unfortunately, links get removed and are not even their text displayed.

Example:

- HTML in RTE: `<p>before <a href="https://cweiske.de/" target="_blank">link</a> after</p>`
- Rendered output in preview: `before after`

How can I get the links in the preview section rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with TYPO3's fluid.

`TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\Format\HtmlViewHelper::simulateFrontendEnvironment()` creates a dummy TSFE instance.

TYPO3's `ContentObjectRenderer` expects `$TSFE->cObjectDepthCounter` to be > 0 when rendering nested tags in `cObjGetSingle`, and this fails because the dummy TSFE instance does not have this variable set.

---

This problem is known since 2015: [Bug #66855: Format/HtmlViewHelper don't render Links in TYPO3_MODE = BE](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/66855)

According to https://forge.typo3.org/issues/67556 and https://forge.typo3.org/issues/96535 this is "fixed" in TYPO3 v11.5 if you switch to [`<f:transform.html>`](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/11.5/en-us/Changelog/11.5/Feature-95176-IntroduceFtransformhtmlView-helper.html).

Answer (score 0):

There was a change in version 9.5.29 due to security reasons.

See: https://typo3.org/security/advisory/typo3-core-sa-2021-013

How to fix: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/9.5.x/Important-94484-IntroduceHTMLSanitizer.html

Comment: This problem already occurs with TYPO3 8.7.32 which does not have the HTML sanitizer, so I do not think this is related. Also, I have the html sanitation log enabled and it is empty.